# sharepoint 2010 workflow error status

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

Hello I'm currently developing a workflow status report(in c#) and I would like to know if there is a way to differentiate between a workflow that was cancelled by a person and a workflow that was cancelled due to an error, I have searched around about this but I haven't found anything specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the Faulting status should solve this :)